Issues running cron jobs at specific times in PostgreSQL using pg_cron
I configured a cron job in PostgreSQL with pg_cron as follows:
SELECT cron.schedule('update-events', '0 0 * * *', 'CALL update_event_active_status()'); 
I expected this job to run every day at midnight. However, when I checked after midnight, I noticed it hadn't executed.
To test, I created a cron job with the same function but scheduled it as follows:
SELECT cron.schedule('update-events', '* * * * *', 'CALL update_event_active_status()'); 
Surprisingly, this job ran correctly every minute (and seemingly every second, as per my monitoring). Still, I cannot get jobs scheduled for specific times (like 0 0 or 30 0) to work properly.
The function used by the cron job is as follows:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_event_active_status()
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
  UPDATE events
  SET is_active = false
  WHERE is_active = true AND date_closing_sales <= current_date;
END;
$$;


Additionally, I configured the PostgreSQL timezone to America/Santiago with:
SET timezone = 'America/Santiago'; 
I verified the timezone settings with:
SHOW timezone;
SELECT NOW();

Both confirmed the server time is correct.
Could there be an issue with pg_cron or the way it handles time-based schedules in PostgreSQL? Am I missing a step to ensure jobs scheduled for specific times work properly?
Any guidance or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

From here pg_cron did you do this: Previously pg_cron could only use GMT time, but now you can adapt your time by setting cron.timezone in postgresql.conf.

Hey, thanks, im running supabase locally for development. I have read the docs so I have to change postgresql.conf file from docker to set cron.timezone, but for production says that is not possible to change cron.timezone

Verify setting cron.timezone localy makes the issue go away or not. If not then there is more work to be done. If it does then you have to work out the production side of things. I'm guessing that is due to the hosted service not allowing you access to postgresql.conf, is that correct? Then again it may not be an issue if the hosted database is running in UTC.

@AdrianKlaveri found the issue, thanks. cron.jobs runs on GMT so if i want the cron execute at 00:00 midnight in Chile i have to set the cron as follow '0 3 * * *'. The only problem is that they have 2 timezones, one for summer and other for winter

No, the fix for the issue is to set cron.timezone to 'America/Santiago'. Then you move on to the next issue which is making this work in the production setup. You might have to reach to Supabase support for this. Though from here Configuration: Every Supabase database is set to UTC timezone by default..

thanks, im going to contact supabase support

Well if you run the production database with the default of timezone='UTC' then it won't be an issue as that is what pg_cron runs in by default.
